# i have 600 records in my postgres database, now when i inserted from django it's generating primary duplication error

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have inserted data into table from postgresql directly. Now when I try to insert data from django application, it's generating primary key duplication error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do not insert data with the same primary key? Question is too broad really.

Comment: Do you have some code you can share (the model). Can you also share the code which you use to insert into the database?

Comment: primary key is auto generated. @favoretti

Comment: class TblProduct(models.Model):
          productType = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
          productName = models.CharField(max_length=500)

Answer (score 0):

Run

**`python manage.py sqlsequencereset [app_name]`**

and **execute** all or just one for the required table SQL **statements in the database** to reset sequences.

---

Explanation:

You probably inserted with primary keys already present in it, not letting postgresql to auto-generate ids. This is ok.

This means, internal Postgresql sequence used to get next available id has old value. You need to rest with sequence to start with maximum id present in the table.

Django `manage.py` has command intended just for that - print sql one can execute in db to reset sequences.

Comment: I have run this command, but still the same duplication error.

Comment: In postgresql table and django model both has auto increment, that's why It's generating error. When I inserted data from django application, id starts from 1 and in my table id = 1 is already exists.

Comment: Did you run result, printed by `python manage.py sqlsequencereset [app_name]` in postgresql cli?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not in database. please check your django code probably you use get_or_create

Comment: I am also inserting from django admin panel, but same duplication error. but I resolved it on temporary basis using get max id and then I add one on it.

Comment: Remove duplicate data form database and also see is there any data with pk 0 ?